# Ping (DUP) with Linux bridges and tap devices

Tags: linux, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, bridge, tap

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XLwU.jpg

I have two Linux (Ubuntu 12.04) VM (running on KVM) that networked together using two Linux bridges as shown above. The network interfaces are Linux TAP devices.

The problem that I am facing is that when I ping from one host to another I see the following

root@ubuntu1204-template:~# ping 192.168.53.42

PING 192.168.53.42 (192.168.53.42) 56(84) bytes of data.

64 bytes from 192.168.53.42: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=1.12 ms

64 bytes from 192.168.53.42: icmp_req=1 ttl=63 time=1.13 ms (DUP!)

Any idea what am I doing wrong ?

I installed arping on the Linux vms and arping does not seem to exhibit this problem.

Comment: Could you please show your br0's detail configuration ?

Answer (score 1):

I removed the PROMISC attribute from the bridge and that fixed the problem

ifconfig br0 -promisc